# Respone.say not working in Promise for Alexa Skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

i´m working on an Alexa Skill with nodejs.
When I want to get a response i don´t get any message when trying to get it with response.say(value). But when trying with console.log(value) i get the right response.

```
alexaApp.intent("Plot", {
    "slots": { "Titel": "String"},
    "utterances": ["Wovon handelt {Titel}"]
},          
function(request, response) {
    var titel = request.slot("Titel");
    geturl(titel,1).then((speech) => {
        console.log(speech); //right string
        response.say(speech); //nothing
    });
});
```

Any ideas how to get it working? I´m working with promises cause of the async of node to get my requests in time.

Answer (score 0):

you should use synchronous call to get request.  here a woking example :

```
   var http = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require('request'), { multiArgs: true });

   app.intent('search', {
    "utterances": [
        "search ",
    ]

  },
  function(request, response) {

    return http.getAsync({ url: url, json: true}).spread(function(statusCodesError, result) {

     console.log(result)

    });


})
```

Answer (score 0):

You do need to use an async call, and return the promise.

```
var http = require('bluebird').promisifyAll(require('request')
   alexaApp.intent("Plot", {
    "slots": { "Titel": "String"},
    "utterances": ["Wovon handelt {Titel}"]
},          
function(request, response) {
    var titel = request.slot("Titel");
    return http.getAsync(titel,1)
         .then((speech) => {
              return response.say(speech); 
         }).catch(function(err){
             return response.say(err);
         });
```